# Android pass object not its value

Tags: android, object, void, updating

How can I update String object from void?
Now it gives me an error: The final local variable sObj cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type.

```
String object = "";
String object2 = "";
String object3 = "";
String object4 = "";
String object5 = "";

digitInput(object); //update string object
digitInput(object4); // update string object4


private void digitInput(final String sObj) {
      ....
      sObj = NEW_VALUE; //With this I want to update passed object
      ....
}
```

Comment: @DavidCAdams is correct. Is that you are looking for? If so you might want to refactor how this is behaving. Post more code or head over to programmers.stackexchange.com for more generalized answers. You might also want to brush up on some java.

Comment: I agree that you need to do some basic Java work.  Note also that everything in Java is passed by value.  To understand why your code didn't work, you need to understand `final`.

Comment: Demonstrates no or minimal understanding of language fundamentals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to reassign the value of the object using the function. The approach you are taking is strange. I would do it like:

```
String object = "";
String object2 = "";
String object3 = "";
String object4 = "";
String object5 = "";

object = digitInput(object); //update string object
object4 = digitInput(object4); // update string object4

// assuming you need the original object to generate the new value
private String digitInput(String sObj) {
      ....
      // do something
      ....
      return NEW_VALUE; //With this I want to update passed object
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's it. I'm a beginner so I forgot I can do this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You want to set the value of object to the value of sObj?  this.object = sObj;

Comment: The problem is that I don't know what String to update from void, so I need to pass specific String with "digitInput(object);" and then update it from void.

Comment: Please, stop guessing.  Learn the basics, then try again. `update it from void` is nonsense.  `void` just indicates to the compiler that a method has no return value.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `final` qualifier from the method signature.

Comment: Now I get: Cannot refer to a non-final variable inside an inner class defined in a different method

Comment: post more code. You probably need to do someting like: String temp = stringYouwant; digitInput(temp); ...

Comment: This is basically all the code.